# Could not read script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' as it does not exist

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I get this error when i run a project on VS code.
Could not read script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle' as it does not exist.
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 4):

For android studio Problem is because Android Studio doesn't know where Flutter is installed in your machine. Same applies to visual studio flutter... You need to explicitly specify this in ***local.properties*** file like I've done below. **(If you have already specified it, make sure you go to that location on your PC to be sure that the location was 100% correct and its all there):**

**(Values used in code below is Just for example.. See my picture for how it looks on an actual machine)**

> sdk.dir=C:\Users\location of where your android sdk is
> flutter.versionName=1.2.0 flutter.sdk=C:\Users\location of where
> your flutter is

**Picture example**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `flutter pub cache repair` this should re-download all the packages and fix any package issues.

Comment: Then I think reinstalling flutter would be a simple option

Comment: `flutter pub cache repair` in fact solved my issue. After changing the flutter path, renaming the already installed flutter path, or moving SDK to another directory you ought to do this. Fixes the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the `android` folder
and run `flutter create .` from the same level as the `android` folder

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does simply not find no deps no plugins.

It happens after a `flutter clean`

Try `flutter pub get` before you build

It worked for me.